# set location for progressbar in swipe refresh layout android

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I used Swipe refresh layout in my app. It worked but I want set location for progress bar in swipe layout margin top 100 px. I don't want use default location of it. How I do? thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could set the offset from top using this `setProgressViewOffset (boolean scale, int start, int end)`

You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setProgressViewOffset(boolean,%20int,%20int)).

Answer (score 9):

In folder res/values create an xml file if you have not already called dimens.xml

Then you can have in it:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="refresher_offset">your_preferred_offset_in_dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="refresher_offset_end">how_long_in_dp_the_swipe</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then take the SwipeRefreshLayout that you have inflated and add on onCreate if you are in Activity or onCreateView if you are in fragment:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false, 
  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.refresher_offset),    
  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.refresher_offset_end));
```

Alternatively you can replace the dimen constants with just a number, but that will mean pixels and the relative position will be different making the implementation problematic in different devices.