# Offset refresh animation in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android

I have the top of a list scroll under a translucent header bar using padding of headerHeight and `android:clipToPadding="false"`. Now the list needs to be in a swipe to refresh layout, and I'm unsure if there is a way to offset just the refresh animation of the `SwipeRefreshLayout`. The code looks like:

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_to_refresh">

    <ListView
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/HeaderHeight"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:id="@+id/location_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="6dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include
android:id="@+id/header"
layout="@layout/header"></include>
```

In a **RelativeLayout**. Anyone that can move the refresh but not `interfere` with the list sliding under the header?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33797487/3166697

Comment: Thanks so much. I was so busy looking for an xml answer I didn't think to just do it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the accepted answer is a comment. I am posting it again as full answer.

You could set the offset from top using this `setProgressViewOffset` shown below:

```
setProgressViewOffset (boolean scale, int start, int end)
```

reference: [setProgressViewOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout#setProgressViewOffset(boolean,%20int,%20int))